How can my transaction be in the same block of the wallet I'm copying?
I have been trying to copy trade some wallets, however I see my transactions always getting in the next block - especially if they snipe new token where volatility and slippage are quite high. Is they any way to be in the same block zero with them even at the cost of high gas price? Thanks

Can you confirm which network you are using and what kind of access you have to it. Question is tagged with mev-boost, are you using flashbots endpoint/bundle methods, or is it a side chain without flashbots, and a regular sendTransaction to a public RPC? Understanding what you have to work with should help people give a higher quality answer.

I'm a newbie in these kind of details, I'm using Maestro Bot as of now, but I'm searching the blockchain topic recently when I was affected with this. Any ideas in general to do this?
